# Show summary for specific docvars

Tags: r, quanteda

I want to give a short summary for a corpus of pdf files. I want to include the columns: Text Types Tokens Sentences (as shown in the quanteda quick start guide) and exclude all other columns. From

```
names(docvars(corp_mk))
```

I got

```
[1] "author"        "datetimestamp" "description"   "heading"       "id"           
[6] "language"      "origin"
```

which should not be shown in the summary.

I tried to use "showmeta = FALSE" in the summary() command, but it still includes all columns.

I am getting:

```
 Text Types Tokens Sentences       author       datetimestamp description
   MoKa_BA_LG_16.pdf  1194   8620       283 Pressestelle 2016-07-27 13:01:04            
  MoKa_BBK_DO_18.pdf   810   2643        56      spalgen 2018-07-03 09:00:13        <NA>
 MoKa_BBK_DUE_18.pdf  1327   6219        97      Suttkus 2018-01-24 14:44:37        <NA>
```

While I want

```
      Text            Types Tokens Sentences       
   MoKa_BA_LG_16.pdf  1194   8620       283          
  MoKa_BBK_DO_18.pdf   810   2643        56      
 MoKa_BBK_DUE_18.pdf  1327   6219        97
```

Do I have to pull columns from the corpus before I can do a summary or can that be done with quanteda commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `summary.corpus()` method silently returns the data.frame that is printed.  So if you just want the textual summary columns, slice them out this way:

```r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 1.4.3
## Parallel computing: 2 of 12 threads used.
## See https://quanteda.io for tutorials and examples.

summary(data_corpus_irishbudget2010)[, c("Text", "Types", "Tokens", "Sentences")]
##                         Text Types Tokens Sentences
## 1        Lenihan, Brian (FF)  1953   8641       374
## 2       Bruton, Richard (FG)  1040   4446       217
## 3         Burton, Joan (LAB)  1624   6393       307
## 4        Morgan, Arthur (SF)  1595   7107       343
## 5          Cowen, Brian (FF)  1629   6599       250
## 6           Kenny, Enda (FG)  1148   4232       153
## 7      ODonnell, Kieran (FG)   678   2297       133
## 8       Gilmore, Eamon (LAB)  1181   4177       201
## 9     Higgins, Michael (LAB)   488   1286        44
## 10       Quinn, Ruairi (LAB)   439   1284        59
## 11     Gormley, John (Green)   401   1030        49
## 12       Ryan, Eamon (Green)   510   1643        90
## 13     Cuffe, Ciaran (Green)   442   1240        45
## 14 OCaolain, Caoimhghin (SF)  1188   4044       176
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you very much.
    [, c("Text", "Types", "Tokens", "Sentences")]
Could you point me to a section of the actual R manual, where I might find some more insight?

Comment: Look at indexing for matrices and data.frames, it’s the same.